# python pandas: transform x-y-list to x-y-coordinate system

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe df like

```
X Y value
1 1 foo
1 2 bar
2 1 lo
2 2 la
```

is there an elegant way to transform it into a x-y-map like

```
  1   2
1 foo bar
2 lo  la
```

Comment: Do you want X and Y to be as column name?

Comment: I corrected the expected result in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try:**

```
df.set_index(['X', 'Y'])['value'].unstack()
```

---

```
Y   1   2
X       
1   foo bar
2   lo  la
```

Comment: very nice solution, maybe just add `df_sol.columns = ['X', 'Y']` and `df_sol.index.name = ''`to get the expected output format? Kr.

Comment: thanks! with @Pygirl s answer I get 1.0 2.0 on X as header instead of 1 2; tried  `df.set_index([int('X'), 'Y'])['value'].unstack()` but this returns an error

Comment: Just follow what antoine has mentioned.  If you want to have them as int then make the column X as int by `df['X'] = df['X'].astype(int)`